# Symfony2: don't update image in db, if it's empty

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have 2 fields logo and images, which I use for storing images. In db they are represented as strings.

```
   /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if ($this->logo !== null) {
            $image_name = uniqid().'.'.$this->logo->guessExtension();
            if($image_name) {
                $this->logo->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $image_name);
                unset($this->logo);
                $this->logo = $image_name;
            }
            else{
                unset($this->logo);
            }
        }
        if(is_array($this->images) && !empty($this->images)){
            $images = array();
            foreach($this->images as $image){
                if($image) {
                    $image_name = uniqid() . '.' . $image->guessExtension();
                    $image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $image_name);
                    $images[] = $image_name;
                }
            }
            if($images){
                $this->images = json_encode($images);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Good.orm.yml**

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
            prePersist: [ preUpload, setCreatedAtValue]
            preUpdate: [ preUpload, setUpdatedAtValue ]
```

Here I move images in right folders and after assign this vars string values. It works well. But I have one problem. If I update another fields, and don't upload new image, I will have empty image fields in db. Symfony erases this fields. How can I change this behavior?

**Creation form:**

```
       /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('logo', FileType::class, array('required' => false, 'data_class' => null))
                ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('images', FileType::class, array('attr' => array("multiple" => "multiple"), 'data_class' => null, 'required' => false))
                ->add('price')
                ->add('is_active')
                ->add('category');
        }
```

**Edit action**

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing good entity.
 *
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Good $good)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($good);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('Shop\ShopBundle\Form\GoodType', $good);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        //return $this->redirectToRoute('app_good_edit', array('id' => $good->getId()));
    }
    $form_edit = $editForm->createView();

    //\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($form_edit->children['images']->vars);

    $form_edit->children['images']->vars = array_replace($form_edit->children['images']->vars, array('full_name' => 'shop_shopbundle_good[images][]'));
    return $this->render('ShopShopBundle:good:edit.html.twig', array(
        'good' => $good,
        'edit_form' => $form_edit,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple work around is the retrive, in the case of `image` field of the form is empy, the old value from the db.
Something like this:

```
if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
    $goodSubmitted = $editForm->getData();
    if(empty($goodSubmitted->getImages()) {
        $goodSaved = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("good repository name here")->find($goodSubmitted->getId());
        $goodSubmitted->setImages($goodSaved->getImages());
    }
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
}
```

I don't know your entity structure, this is just an idea.

If you want to edit in order to add an image, you have to handle that too.

However, this could be painful. My advice is to keep things simple: create one entity for all images and link to your `Good` entity with a proper relationship.
I've found that [article](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/07/manage-multiple-files-upload-in-symfony/) describing the above structure.

Comment: I've tried first method, but `$goodSaved->getImages())` always return null, although there is such value in db. Of course, I will try second method, but I wanna finish first method.